# How to link to the standard libraries statically in flang-new like GFortran?

Tags: cmake, fortran, clang, flang

I have a C++ project that uses Fortran.

When compiling under GCC, I can link in Fortran statically using `target_link_libraries(Project -static-libgfortran gfortran)`.

However, I am now compiling the same project using Clang, which means instead of gfortran I am using Flang. (flang-new version 15.0.7)

If I don't include any replacement, I get a lot of undefined symbols, like `_FortranAioBeginExternalFormattedOutput`.

If I try to swap out those two with just "flang", it fails, saying:

```
lld: error: unable to find library -lflang
```

LLVM has a single sentence on linking flang, which I don't follow:

"After the LLVM IR is created, the flang driver invokes LLVM’s existing infrastructure to generate object code and invoke a linker to create the executable file."

How do I link in Flang the same way I did GFortran?

Comment: any difference if you use [`target_link_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_options.html) instead for that linker flag? It's not really a library (linker flags in `target_link_libraries` should be ok [according to the docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html), but I'm just curious to see if anything changes).

Comment: `-static-libgfortran` is listed in https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#fortran-compilation-flags. What if you instead use `target_compile_options(Project PUBLIC -static-libgfortran)` (or `PRIVATE`)?

Answer (score 0):

`-static-libgfortran` is listed in https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#fortran-compilation-flags. Try using `target_compile_options(Project PUBLIC -static-libgfortran)` (or `PRIVATE`).

##### For Classic Flang

[The compiler option docs](https://github.com/flang-compiler/flang#compiler-options) don't list a [`-static-libgfortran`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Link-Options.html) flag, but they do list a `-static-flang-libs`. Try using that instead. But since it's listed as a compiler option, I'd try using `target_compile_options`.

If you want to support both GFortran and Flang, then wrap the `target_link_options` / `target_link_libraries` calls in `if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU")` or `if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "Flang")` (see docs for [`CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_ID`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_ID.html)), or use the [`$<Fortran_COMPILER_ID:...>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:Fortran_COMPILER_ID) generator expression.

If this is a linker flag, I'd recommend [`target_link_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_options.html) for linker options instead of `target_link_libraries` just for readability's sake (using `target_link_libraries` should work too though [according to the docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html)).

Note: I found the info about the `-static-flag-libs` flag by googling "`"flang" "-static-libgfortran"`", where my top search result was [this SciVision post](https://www.scivision.dev/gfortran-static-missing-dll/), which showed the `-static-flang-libs` flag. Then a google of "`"flang" "-static-flang-libs"`" led me to the Flang GitHub. Tip for googling flags that start with a dash: [enclose in double-quotes to avoid it being used as a exclusion operator](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/168474/305006).

Comment: The link you mention is for Classic Flang. There was a schism and we have two Flangs. The "classic flang" that requires a special fork of LLVM, and there is "new flang" which is part of main LLVM.

Getting classic flang would involve recompiling all of LLVM, which I am not keen to do for many reasons.

For thoroughness, neither -static-flang-libs or flang are recognized by the linker. Those exist for classic flang, not "new flang".